# Prove that $\mathbb E [T_n(x) ~ T_n(y)] = nF_X(x) + n(n - 1)F_X(x)F_X(y)$, for $x<y.$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X_1, \cdots,X_n $ be iid random variables with distribution $F. T_n(x)$ denotes the number of elements $\le x; x \in \mathbb R$. Prove that $\mathbb E [T_n(x) ~ T_n(y)] = nF_X(x) + n(n - 1)F_X(x)F_X(y)$, for $x<y$.

**Attempt**

Let $j = T_n(y) ,i = T_n(x)$. Then

$\mathbb E [T_n(x) ~ T_n(y)] = \sum_{j = 0}^n ~\sum_{i = 0} ^j ~ ^jC_i~ [F_X(x)]^i [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j-i} \cdot j \cdot i$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j \cdot [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j}~~\sum_{i = 0} ^j ~ ^jC_i~ \dfrac {[F_X(x)]^i} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{i}} \cdot i$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j}~ \dfrac {[F_X(x)]} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]} ~~\sum_{i = 0} ^j ~ ^{j-1}C_{i-1}~ \dfrac {[F_X(x)]^{i-1}} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{i-1}}$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j-1}~ {[F_X(x)]}~\sum_{i = 1} ^j ~ ^{j-1}C_{i-1}~ \dfrac {[F_X(x)]^{i-1}} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{i-1}}$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j-1}~ {[F_X(x)]}~~\sum_{m = 0} ^{j-1} ~ ^{j-1}C_m~ \dfrac {[F_X(x)]^m} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^m}$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j-1}~ {[F_X(x)]}~\big( \dfrac {[F_X(x)]} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]} +1 \big)^{j-1}$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j-1}~ {[F_X(x)]}~\big( \dfrac {[F_X(y)]} {[F_X(y) - F_X(x)]} \big)^{j-1}$

$= \sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot {[F_X(x)]}~{[F_X(y)]}^{j-1} $

$= \dfrac{F_X(x)}{F_X(y)}\sum_{j = 0}^n j^2 \cdot ~{[F_X(y)]}^{j} $

This doesn't lead to the result being proved. Could someone advise?

Comment: Follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3766585/321264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand how you get you first equality. What I see is $$\begin{align*}
E\left[T_n(x)T_n(y)\right] &= \sum_{i,j=1}^ni\,j\,P[T_n(x)=i,\,T_n(y)=j]\\
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^ni\,j\,P[X_{(i)}\leq x,\,X_{(j)}\leq y]
\end{align*}$$ and I don't get the remaining. Maybe there is a problem there.

**Answer I propose:**

First, you should remark that $T_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}$ and $T_n(y) = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq x\}}$ and $$\begin{align*}
T_n(x)T_n(y) &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq \min(x,\,y)\}} + \sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\\
T_n(x)T_n(y)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}} + \sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\\
\end{align*}$$
Then, $$\begin{align*}
E\left[T_n(x)T_n(y)\right] &= E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\right] + E\left[\sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^n\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nE\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\right] + \sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^nE\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nE\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\right] + \sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^nE\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}\right]E\left[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_j\leq y\}}\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nP\left[X_i\leq x\right] + \sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^nP\left[X_i\leq x\right]P\left[X_j\leq y\right]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^nF(x) + \sum_{i,j=1\\j\neq i}^nF(x)F(y)\\
&= nF(x) + n(n-1)F(x)F(y)\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I would be grateful if you could also take a look at my attempt. Could you advise if I have been wrong anywhere?

Comment: I don't really get you first equality. So, I can not say where exactly there is a problem. You should maybe check it.

Comment: $P[X_{(i)}\leq x,\,X_{(j)}\leq y]  = \sum_{j = 0}^n ~\sum_{i = 0} ^j ~ ^jC_i~ [F_X(x)]^i [F_X(y) - F_X(x)]^{j-i}$

Comment: This equation seem weird. In fact for $j=0$, the sum is $1$. So the result you give is always greater than $1$.

Comment: I am sorry $P(T_n(x) = i, T_n(y) = j )  = ~~^jC_i  ~F(x)^i \cdot [F(y) - F(x)]^{j-i}$

Comment: i.e. out of  $j$ variables which are less than $y$, select $i$ of them to be less than $x$. The remaining $j-i$ will lie between $x$ and $y$

Comment: Now $j$ varies between $0$ and $n$. and $i$ will vary between $0$ and $j$. That's how i obtained that formula

Comment: You agree with me that $P(T_n(x)=0,T_n(y)=0) = \prod_{i=1}^nP[X_i\geq y] = [1-F_X(y)]^n$? 
Meaning that all variables are greater that $y$. Using your formula, we can not get this.

Comment: gottcha. I missed a term there : $P(T_n(x)=i,T_n(y)=j)=  ~^jC_i F(x)^i⋅[F(y)−F(x)]^{j−i} (1 - F(y))^{n-j}$

Comment: In the third last line, how did $E [ \mathbb 1_{X_i \le y} ] $ become equal to $P(X_i \le x)$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128945/discussion-between-abdoul-haki-and-mathman).